# C++ TCP telnet not properly reading read bytes

Tags: c++, tcp

I am using [this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-in-cc-handling-multiple-clients-on-server-without-multi-threading/) to create a chat room.

I noticed that whenever I add prints to see the data read in from the buffer, I don't get the input that I sent.

For example, I will start my server and then connect to it using `telnet localhost 8888`.

Then I will send the message "Testing Send".

I configured my server to print out each character between '-':

```
//Check if it was for closing , and also read the
//incoming message
if ((valread = read( sd , buffer, BUFFER_SIZE)) == 0)
{
    //Somebody disconnected , get his details and print
    getpeername(sd , (struct sockaddr*)&address , (socklen_t*)&addrlen);
    printf("Host disconnected , ip %s , port %d \n" ,
        inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr) , ntohs(address.sin_port));

    //Close the socket and mark as 0 in list for reuse
    close( sd );
    client_socket[i] = 0;
} else {
    for (int j = 0; j < BUFFER_SIZE; j++) {
        printf ("-%c-", buffer[j]);
    }
}
```

When I do this I get the following print:

```
Listener on port 8888
Waiting for connections ...
New connection , socket fd is 4 , ip is : 127.0.0.1 , port : 59080
Welcome message sent
successfully Adding to list of sockets as 0
----e--s--t--i--n--g-- --S--e--n--d--
```

Notice how the first character was lost. What could cause this?

Comment: First of all your loop should be `j < valread`, not `j < BUFFER_SIZE`.

Comment: `valread ` will be the number of bytes read, not `BUFFER_SIZE`. `recv` promises up to `BUFFER_SIZE`, not exactly `BUFFER_SIZE`.

Comment: Carriage Returns: after your "Testing Send" text, there'll be a carriage return character, that when printed to a terminal returns the cursor to the leftmost column, then you're overwriting the 'T' you'd printed earlier.  To verify this, `printf("-%d-"` instead and check the ASCII codes.

Comment: `read()` returns -1 on error, and 0 on *graceful* disconnect. So the `if` should check for `<= 0` instead of `== 0`